# Tile Maps in Java JFrame Game

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I am making a 2D Java game with Java's own drawing library. I was wondering how I would make a tile map display on the screen. I would prefer to use a GUI application to make the maps. I'm looking for orthogonal projection: a top down view.

Comment: What type of display are you trying to get? Do you want it in [perspective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perspective_%28graphical%29), as an [isometric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isometric_projection) projection or in [top-down](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_game_graphics#Top-down_perspective) perspective?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I was looking for top-down view: 'orthogonal' projection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using [Tiled Map Editor](http://www.mapeditor.org/). This editor has GUI for you to import tiles, make maps and outputs in XML format. You will need to parse the XML data in your game according to your needs. The XML format is described [here](https://github.com/bjorn/tiled/wiki/TMX-Map-Format) and you can refer to this page for  [java XML parsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373833/best-xml-parser-for-java). There is a lot of [sample games made with Tiled](https://github.com/bjorn/tiled/wiki/Games-made-with-Tiled) and documentation [here](https://github.com/bjorn/tiled/wiki).

Comment: Just to add to xiao's post, slick2D has a tiled map editor parser built into it so you can use that game library if need be

Comment: Thanks, I made my own maps in text files, and rendered the maps manually.